# Richfaces 4 a4j:commandLink action not firing in rich:popupPanel

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, cdi, jboss-weld, commandlink

I seem to be having a problem where I have an a4j:commandLink on a rich:popupPanel but the action is not firing.  The xhtml looks as follows:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="rate-panel" modal="true" height="444" width="780" top="60" show="false" onmaskclick="#{rich:component('rate-panel')}.hide()" styleClass="cs-modal">
  /**Some html here**/    
  <a4j:commandLink immediate="false" action="#{venueScore.up}" render="rate-panel" styleClass="rate love">
    <span>Love it</span>
  </a4j:commandLink>    
  /**Some more html here**/    
</rich:popupPanel>
```

And the managed bean looks as follows:

```
@Named("venueScore")
@ViewScoped
public class VenueScoreManager extends BaseManager implements Serializable {
  public void up() {
    System.out.println("TEST");
    //Do something
  }
}
```

I have made the managed bean @ViewScoped.

I have also tried adding an `<h:form>` around the commandLink however, this does even less than without it.  I actually think that is because the commandLink is inside the `<h:form>` in which the link that opened the popupPanel sits.

Anyway, can someone please point me in the direction of why the action not fire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed it myself.  After screwing around I worked out that I just need to add an `<a4j:region>` around the content in the `<rich:popupPanel>`.  So now the xhtml looks something like this:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="rate-panel" modal="true" height="444" width="780" top="60" show="false" onmaskclick="#{rich:component('rate-panel')}.hide()" styleClass="cs-modal">
  <a4j:region id="panel-region">
    /**Some html here**/    
    <a4j:commandLink immediate="false" action="#{venueScore.up}" render="panel-region" styleClass="rate love">
      <span>Love it</span>
    </a4j:commandLink>    
    /**Some more html here**/    
  </a4j:region>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Comment: You cannot believe how much time i spent trying to find this answer! How did you reach this solution ?

Comment: @AmrH.AbdelMajeed - I probably spent just as much time as you.  Trial and error in the end I think solved it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, a4j:commandLink **only worked after first click**.... put the poppanel inside a form and add domElementAttachment...

```
<h:form id="myform">
    <rich:popupPanel id="pop" domElementAttachment="form">
        ...
        <a4j:commandLink />
        ...
    </rich:popupPanel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old question but as I had exactly the same problem, I spent a lot of time before fixing it, maybe it will help someone else.
First, I tried the solution proposed above but it did not worked.
Finally, I found this thread:
[Issues closing rich:popupPanel via show condition, RF 4.0](https://community.jboss.org/message/602113#602113)

And I added the domElement attribute to my popup:

```
<rich:popupPanel 
id="newMailPopup" 
**domElementAttachment="form"** 
...>
```

And now, my a4j:commandLink works perfectly :-)